# FIX: Ipad Mini HTML margin/padding with <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I had a website with:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

...that was applying a strange "margin-right: 30px"-like behaviour to the html DOM element. Removing this fixed the issue.

Declaring

```
<doctype !html>
```

Already gives you IE=edge, and I'm happy for the site not to use chrome=1.

Answer (score 0):

Contributing this in case anyone else encounters it - it probably wasted 6 - 7 hours of dev time over the last week trying to find it.